# Match tuple values within the list

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

Compare tuples within a list, I have list which contains details of the address, and i need to compare if two address's are same or not,

```
address1= [('1546-1711', 'AddressNumber'),
  ('South', 'StreetNamePreDirectional'),
  ('4650', 'AddressNumber'),
  ('West,', 'StreetNamePostDirectional'),
  ('Green', 'PlaceName'),
  ('Lake', 'PlaceName'),
  ('town,', 'PlaceName'),
  ('MI', 'StateName'),
  ('84107', 'ZipCode')]

 address2 = [('800', 'AddressNumber'),
  ('Green', 'StreetName'),
  ('Lake', 'PlaceName'),
  ('town,', 'PlaceName'),
  ('MI', 'StateName'),
  ('84110', 'ZipCode')]
```

There are some attibutes which are missing in second address like 'StreetNamePreDirectional' and 'StreetNamePostDirectional', so i have to compare on the remaining attributes whichever is present, so first i need to check what attributes are common between both and then compare if they have matching values, what's the pythonic way to do it

My code so far:

```
for item1 in add2:
    for item2 in add1:
        if(item2[1]=='AddressNumber' and item1[1]=='AddressNumber'):
            addressnumbermatch = True
        if(item2[1]=='StreetNamePreDirectional' == item1[1]=='StreetNamePreDirectional'):
            StreeNameDirectionMatch = True
        if(item2[1]=='StreetNamePreDirectional' == item1[1]=='StreetNamePreDirectional'):
            StreetNamePreDirectionalMatch = True

if(addressnumbermatch and StreeNameDirectionMatch and StreetNamePreDirectionalMatch ):
    # Do somthing
```

Note: There are multiple attibutes like AddressNumber and Place Name so it should match any one value out of multiple values. so first address contains two Address number so need to check if any of these two values matches with the Address number of Address2

Comment: You'll need to describe a bit more thoroughly how you determine if two addresses are equal. For example, how do you resolve fields that show up multiple times in an address (e.g. AddressNumber and PlaceName)?

Comment: Explained how to resolve if multiple attributes are available within a address

Answer (score 1):

(Apart from the issue @glibdud pointed out) The way to go, I think, is to use `set`.

```
s1 = set(address1)
s2 = set(address2)
common = s1.intersection(s2)
```

Of course you can use more set operations to determine whether the overlap is enough evidence of being similar, but we do not have that information on your data.

In this case, it will output:

```
s1.intersection(s2)
Out[31]: {('Lake', 'PlaceName'), ('MI', 'StateName'), ('town,', 'PlaceName')}
```

In the end, I get the feeling from the definition of the question where one of the two can contain multiple addresses that you want to know whether an address is listed in your address register. In that case instead of `intersection` you'll want to use `s1.issuperset(s2)` or `s2.issubset(s1)`, which returns you a nice `bool` to work with.

```
s1.issuperset(s2)
>> False
```

Comment: No, this doesn;t work as expected, even I tried using set

Comment: Can you describe how this does not work as expected? I get a nice non-empty intersection, denoting a degree of similarity between the two

Comment: You are correct, it gives exact match..My bad, didn't verified the result correctly..

Answer (score 1):

a good way to do this is to have a function that will extract the information you need from the tuple list i.e.

```
def get_address_info(address_data):
    address_number = None
    street_name_pre_directional = None
    street_name_post_directional = None

    for value, property_name in address_data:
        if property_name == "AddressNumber":
            address_number = value
        elif property_name == "StreetNamePreDirectional":
            street_name_pre_directional = value
        elif property_name == "StreetNamePostDirectional":
            street_name_post_directional = value

    return address_number, street_name_pre_directional, street_name_post_directional
```

that way you dont have to compare the items with each another, and the maintenance is easier
now you can get the necessary data and compare them directly and determine whether some information is missing by checking whether `None` is present in the info

```
add1_info = get_address_info(add1)
add2_info = get_address_info(add2)
if add1_info  == add2_info and None not in add1_info and None not in add2_info :
    #do something...
```